# How to prevent Slick.js Carousel from making 2 rows (centerMode: true) when page width is very low?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, slick.js

I'm using slick.js with `centerMode: true`. Now the issue is ... when I reduce the page width/div width and it's too low, it ends up making two rows. How do I prevent this? I'd have considered using `overflow: hidden` and hiding the excess because that doesn't really affect how it works, but the buttons also are readjusting and It ends up being placed in the wrong place. how do I fix this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/our-carousel-forked-2tp6g?file=/src/App.js

you can check this to get the issue ... I've just altered an example I found online to recreate the problem. As you bring it closer, you can see the arrows going down because 2 rows are formed.

images:

[image: before]

before ^

[image: after reducing width]

after reducing width ^

how do I fix this?

Comment: Your images are not have same size, so that issue was come use :`.slick-track {display:flex;}`

Comment: lol in my actual code the images are the same size but I tried your snippet anyways just cuz I was bored and had nothing to do ... it solved my problem lmaooooo! thanks! if you write an answer I'll mark it :D